# How to get file path in jsp page while adding a file

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am working on file uploading in spring. Here I have one extra requirement that is **when I am uploading a file from local system lets say,**

```
d:/file/xyz.pdf      //I want to upload this file from this location.
```

at same time I have one option to view this file in a modal window.(**Note:** Before saving it into database).

If I am taking a static file and storing it in my local(in side webapp/WEB-INF) then I am able to show that in modal window.

**My question is** when end user will choose a file randomly from some drive how I will get that path for view this.

Or if you have any other idea please share with me how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this.

```
var file = document.getElementbyId("fileName").files[0]; 
//file_url=URL.createObjectURL(file); 
document.getElementById("viewsrc").href=URL.createObjectURL(file);
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```